# Ridge Regression derivation - vector to matrix

Tags: least-squares

$ \min_w \frac{1}{2N} (y_n - x_n^Tw)^2 + \lambda ||w||^2 $

$ \frac{d}{dw} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x_n^Tw)x_n + 2\lambda w $

$ w = (X^TX + \lambda 2N I)^{-1} X^Ty $

How do I go from line 2 to 3 ? How do I change from a vector to a matrix ? I can only derive until line 2.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to view the original objective function in terms of matrices and vectors.

Your original objective function is missing a summation, it should read:

$$
\frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (y_n - \mathbf{x_n}^T \mathbf{w})^2 + \lambda ||\mathbf{w}||^2
$$
I've also made the vectors bold in the above expression.

This expression can be written using vectors and matrices.
Let $\mathbf{y}$ be the vector with components $y_{n}$, $1 \le n \le N$.

Let $X$ be the data matrix whose $n^{th}$ column is $\mathbf{x_{n}}$. The vector of coefficients is $\mathbf{w}$

The summation in the objective function is the norm of a vector so we can write the function as follows:

$$
\frac{1}{2N} \left\lVert \mathbf{y} - X^{T} \mathbf{w} \right\rVert^{2}
+ \lambda ||\mathbf{w}||^2
$$

Which can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{2N} \left( \mathbf{y} - X^{T} \mathbf{w} \right)^{T}
\left( \mathbf{y} - X^{T} \mathbf{w} \right)
+ \lambda \mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{w}
$$

Expanding:
$$
\frac{1}{2N} 
\left[\;
\mathbf{y}^{T} \mathbf{y}
- \mathbf{y}^{T} X^{T} \mathbf{w}
- \mathbf{w}^{T} X \mathbf{y}
+ \mathbf{w}^{T} X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
\;\right]
+ \lambda \mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{w}
$$

We have $\mathbf{y}^{T} X^{T} \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w}^{T} X \mathbf{y}$ so we can write:
$$
\frac{1}{2N} 
\left[\;
\mathbf{y}^{T} \mathbf{y}
- 2 \mathbf{w}^{T} X \mathbf{y}
+ \mathbf{w}^{T} X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
\;\right]
+ \lambda \mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{w}
$$

Differentiating with respect to $\mathbf{w}$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
\frac{1}{2N} 
\left[\;
- 2  X \mathbf{y}
+ 2 X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
\;\right]
+ 2 \lambda  \mathbf{w}
\\
=&
- \frac{1}{N}   X \mathbf{y}
+ \frac{1}{N}  X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
+ 2 \lambda  \mathbf{w}
\end{aligned}
$$

Setting this to zero
$$
\begin{aligned}
- \frac{1}{N}   X \mathbf{y}
+ \frac{1}{N}  X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
+ 2 \lambda  \mathbf{w} 
&= 0
\\
X X^{T} \mathbf{w}
+ 2 N \lambda  \mathbf{w} 
&= 
X \mathbf{y}
\\
\left(
X X^{T}
+ 2 N \lambda I
\right)
\mathbf{w} 
&= 
X \mathbf{y}
\end{aligned}
$$

To give finally
$$
\mathbf{w} 
=
\left(
X X^{T}
+ 2 N \lambda I
\right)^{-1}
X \mathbf{y}
$$

I'm not sure why I end up with a slightly different expression from your one. Please let me know if you can see why.